# `this` return value of parent object and not the current function

Tags: javascript, this

I'm not sure that I am approaching this the besst way but I really want to understand why this happend.

```js
var sessionMethods = {
  isOnline: function (s) { /* */ },
  isOffline: function (s) { /* */ },
};

function defaultCallback() {
  if (typeof arguments[0] !== 'object') {
    arguments[0] = {};
  } else if ('session' in arguments[0]) {
    arguments[0] = arguments[0].session;
  }
  // Here this has for value session object !!
  // i want to access session[currentFunction].callback
  return this.callback.apply(this, arguments);
}

var session = {};
for (var key in sessionMethods) {
  session[key] = defaultCallback;
  session[key].callback = sessionMethods[key];
}
```

My ultimate goal is to be able to avoid redundant code by adding some sort of middleware function that would convert request to request session if nescessary and maybe do more stuff later on.

But if i could undrestand a bit more how `this` work, that would be great !

Comment: Like this? http://jsbin.com/qeqipekudanu/1/

Comment: Yes this work, i guess it's time to read some doc about `bind()` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i now understand how `this` work and what `bind()` does thanks to **limelights** [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26275845/this-return-value-of-parent-object-and-not-the-current-function#comment-41224745).

Here is my understanding of it : `this` never represent the current function object but it's the object that called the function, we can specify a context with bind to make sure that the function is called with the proper `this` object.

Answer (score -1):

If you assign 'this' to a variable then the context will be stored.

```
  // Here this has for value session object !!
  // i want to access session[currentFunction].callback
  var self = this;  // <-- assign this to a variable.
  return this.callback.apply(self , arguments);
```

Comment: Nope at this point `this` doesn't have the callback so it's impossible to call `apply()` of undefined